# Is it possible to upsert documents in mondodb by an array of ids, so that each new created document's _id is the one from the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my Rails project with mongodb, I retrieve user ids from twitter which I want to store in my User model. The plan is to upsert the collection of Users with the retrieved user ids I have in an array, and set every new created document _id to the corresponding user id from the array.

So when I do something like this:

```
Tweep.collection.find( _id: 1234567 ).modify( { "$set" => {a: true}, "$unset" => {c: ""} }, {upsert: true})enter code here
```

The result is like expected: `<Tweep _id: 1234567, a(active): true, c(candidate_value): nil>`

Now I want to do the same, but only passing an array of ids to upsert my collection on Users:

```
Tweep.collection.find(_id: {"$in" =>[123124,223553,6343643,23423]}, c: { "$exists" => true }).modify( { "$set" => {p: true}, "$inc" => {c: 1} }, {upsert: true})
```

The result is some newly created documents, but without the desired values as _id e.g. _id: 123124:

```
<Tweep _id: 5244501325fed0cfd2c1a615, a(active): nil, c(candidate_value): 1>
```

instead of:

```
<Tweep _id: 123124, a(active): nil, c(candidate_value): 1>
```

How can I make mongodb use the user id in my array to be the id for the field _id?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. From [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter):

> If upsert is set to true and if no document matches the query
>   criteria, update() inserts a *single* document.

Then again, you write:

> The result is some newly created documents

I *hope* that it's really only one document. With a query that contains only `_id : {$in : [...]}`, it wouldn't even insert a single document on my machine (MongoDB 2.5.0). It only inserts if I add more criteria. Could you check that again?

It's  hard to come up with a meaningful definition of how this should behave. Combining `$in` can be tricky. Let's say you have two documents:

```
{ _id : 1, name : "John" }
{ _id : 2, name : "Jane" }
```

and you call

```
db.update({"_id" : {$in : [1,2]}, "name" : "Max"}, { ... }, { upsert: true});
```

What is supposed to happen? There is no document that has `_id` 1 or 2 *and* name equals "Max", so the upsert would have to insert... well, what? Maybe two documents with the name Max? If the array were larger, we'd create a *ton* of 'Max's which probably wasn't our intention (the semantics would be: "update one or insert a thousand", which is odd). So let's say we only insert one. But now, which `_id` to choose? And, of course, there is the problem that `_id` is a unique key, so in the example, both would fail.

Comment: I see your point, thanks for clarfication. My intention is to let mongodb do the work of creating a bunch of documents with the passed array of ids. I try to avoid doing "for array.length" mongodb queries in order to create new documents for every id in the array and set values like "$set" => {p: true}, "$inc" => {c: 1}. Is there a way to let mongodb do the work of creating a new document and set some values for each id an array contains?

Comment: Unfortunately, anno 2018 with the `updateMany` method this is disappointingly still the case.